# Catalog Search index error After updating Magento 2.4.0 to 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2, indexer

When I run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get the following error message from the Catalog Search indexer:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [sku] not found for field [sku]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [sku] not found for field [sku]"},"status":400}
```

I have checked that elasticSearch 7 is connected and running. I have disabled a search autocomplete plugin (https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-search-autocomplete-free.html) and that also did not resolve the issue.

I noticed some others had issues but mainly due to a mirasvit plugin which I do not have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to your ElasticSearch installation or version.

Check if you're using ElasticSearch 7.9 [as required](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html) and try to reset the indexes before run the reindex.

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

[image: Magento 2 ElasticSearch error]

Comment: Looking into this now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Host told me that they don't support 7.9 yet. Looks like I'll have to wait, or move the site to another server. Your answer seems most probably even though I won't be able to test it for a little while.